# Correlation between hotter peppers and further ripening

Tags: peppers, ripening

I have read that the more red a hot pepper is, the hotter the pepper. Drying also increases the heat. However my momma says that the more red a hot pepper is, the fruiter it is which suggests that since I like very few kinds of hot peppers(only a lot or a few banana peppers and only a few jalapenos) that if I do grow hot peppers, I should let them completely ripen.

But is this correlation between the color of the pepper and the heat of the pepper true that the redder the pepper, the hotter the pepper? Or is my momma right on that the redder peppers are fruitier regardless of whether they are sweet peppers or hot peppers?

Comment: I would suggest looking at this question:
http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14110/is-there-a-way-to-harvest-my-chilli-peppers-for-the-best-possible-heat?rq=1